# how can I add url filter in php?

Tags: php, server, host

Recently, I am using Hostgator as my php web server.

But I can access and download the public html files in the url. Is this normal?

Can I control the urls access right by php or anything?

like only "abc.com" this direct can access

"abc.com/files" cannot direct access

Thanks for helping

Comment: you can create such rules with `.htaccess` for apache

Answer (score 1):

Check if the variable $url is a valid URL:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.hackingworldtips.wordpress.com";

if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
    echo("$url is a valid URL");
} else {
    echo("$url is not a valid URL");
}
?>
```

Definition and Usage
The FILTER_VALIDATE_URL filter validates a URL.

Possible  flags:

FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED - URL must be RFC compliant (like http://example)
FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED - URL must include host name (like http://www.example.com)
FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED - URL must have a path after the domain name (like www.example.com/example1/)
FILTER_FLAG_QUERY_REQUIRED - URL must have a query string (like "example.php?name=Peter&age=37")

**The example below both sanitizes and validates an URL:**

Example 1
First remove all illegal characters from the $url variable, then check if it is a valid URL:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.hackingworldtips.wordpress.com";

// Remove all illegal characters from a url
$url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

// Validate url
if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
    echo("$url is a valid URL");
} else {
    echo("$url is not a valid URL");
}
?>
```

Example 2
Here, the URL is required to have a query string to be valid:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.hackingworldtips.wordpress.com";

if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_QUERY_REQUIRED) === false) {
    echo("$url is a valid URL");
} else {
    echo("$url is not a valid URL");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a .htaccess file with this code in files folder(any folder which you want to prevent from public acess)

```
  Order Deny,Allow 
  Deny from all
```